# Is there a function equivalent to the Oracle's NVL in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, coalesce, nvl

I'm selecting the max of a column from a table. But there is one problem: if there are no rows in the table, it returns null.

I want to use a function which will return a certain value if the result is null. For example with Oracle there is the `NVL` function which gives a certain value if the column is null. Is there an equivalent function in MySQL ?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Use [coalesce](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce):

```
select coalesce(column_name, 'NULL VALUE') from the_table
```

Comment: That is the SQL standard version of NVL, and works in Oracle, too (since 9i, I believe).

Comment: The question asks _"But there is one problem: if there are no rows in the table, it returns null."_  However, coalesce doesn't solve this - if no rows are returned, then no rows are returned.  All it does is ensure a non-null value for a certain column *given some rows are returned*  But then, neither does nvl in oracle :)

Comment: @Adam. The aggregate function `max` will return a single row (with null in it) even if there are no rows in the table. All the coalesce does (and all the question asked about) is change that null to a default value.

Answer (score 0):

or you can use **IFNULL(expr1,expr2)**

If expr1 is not NULL, IFNULL() returns expr1; otherwise it returns expr2.

*select IFNULL(column_name, 'NULL VALUE') from the_table;*

taken from:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/flow-control-functions.html#function_ifnull